# How to change the output format of a built-in function

Tags: output-formatting

Is it possible to change the output of build-in functions?

I would like to change the output for IdentityMatrix[n] to "I", so I tried

```
Format[IdentityMatrix[n]] := "I"
```

For comparison I also tried

```
Format[Sin[x_]] := "Sine(" <> ToString[x] <> ")"
```

Both result into an error:
"Tag IdentityMatrix in IdentityMatrix[n] is Protected."

I guess these functions are protected because they are build-in functions. Is there a way to change the output format of a build-in function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either [`Unprotect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unprotect.html) the symbol, or use `MakeBoxes` instead

```
MakeBoxes[IdentityMatrix[_], StandardForm] := "I"
MakeBoxes[Sin[x_], StandardForm] := "Sine(" <> ToString[x] <> ")"
```

Just know that this last option provides a default way of formatting, it doesn't override anything if there already is a rule

Comment: The matrix identity thing doesn't work for me in version 9. Do I need to do something else? I guess it evaluates to {{1,0},{0,1},...} before it gets to format it.